# Post Image on Twitter

Tags: angularjs, cordova, twitter, ionic-framework, angular-http

I am developing an app. I have done Login Using OAuth. Now i want to post an Image to my Twitter Account.But each time i am getting Capacity Over Error message.I tried with Both media and media_data after converting my String into Base64.I am trying with Ionic and Angular JS.You can also suggest me any Other Solution.
My code is below.

```
        var clientId = "**************";
        var clientSecret = "*****************";
        /** Twitter oauth for User Details **/
        // Accessing profile info from twitter
        var oauthObject = {
            oauth_consumer_key: clientId,
            oauth_nonce: $cordovaOauthUtility.createNonce(10),
            oauth_signature_method: "HMAC-SHA1",
            oauth_token: token.oauth_token,
            oauth_timestamp: Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000.0),
            oauth_version: "1.0"
        };
       var signatureObj = $cordovaOauthUtility.createSignature("POST", "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json" , oauthObject, { }, clientSecret, token.oauth_token_secret);
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = signatureObj.authorization_header;
         //$http.post(url, {media_data: 'base64'},{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).success(function(
         $http.post(url, {media: 'Image URL'},{headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}).success(function(result) {
            console.log(result)
            })
          .error(function(result) {
              console.log(result)
            });
```

Any Body can help me in this Problem.

Comment: How big is your image? Does it work with sending tweets only? Let us know your total size. thanks!

Comment: @Gene Image is less then 5Mb  and it works fine for Tweet Only.

Comment: Try to lower it to below 3mb and try.

Comment: @Gene I have tried with 100kb also ..:(

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: @Ozi see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried these :

https://github.com/saimon24/ng-twitter

https://devdactic.com/twitter-rest-api-angularjs/

I sent Base64 String in Post request.

```
var MEDIA_UPLOAD_URL = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json';

//A custom function in Twitte Api
postMedia: function (base64Media, parameters) {
  return postRequest(MEDIA_UPLOAD_URL, {media: base64Media}, parameters);
},
```

Comment: Selam Muhammad, thank you for help and what can be parameters do you know about it ?

Comment: @Ozi parameters are optional Parameters .First two are important.
URL and ImageString.